# find probability of $(A\cap B)$.

Tags: probability

There are two red pens, one green pen and one blue pen. Two pens are chosen without replacement. Let $A$ be the event that we choose exactly one red pen and $B$ be the event that we choose exactly one green pen. Then find $P(A\cap B)$.

I think we should use $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)=4/12+3/12-?$. Kind of stuck here.

Sorry it may be very easy but Probability is my weak point.

Comment: "There are two red pens, one green and one red pen. "

Comment: sorrrrry edited

Comment: I still do not understand. Do you have 4 pens in total (3 red and 1 green)?

Comment: ohhh sorry. It should be clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this directly:  $A \cap B$ is the event of picking one red and one green pen out of those two pens.  So: you can either pick a red pen and then a green pen (probability is $P(RG) = \frac{2}{4} * \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{12}$), or first a green pen and then a red pen (probability is $P(GR) = \frac{1}{4} * \frac{2}{3} = \frac{2}{12}$).

So, $P(A \cap B) = P(RG)+ P(GR) = \frac{2}{12}+ \frac{2}{12} = \frac{4}{12} = \frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose two pens. In the event $A\cap B$ you know that you chose a red pen *and* a green pen. How many possibilities? $2$. In how many ways you choose 2 pens? $\binom{4}{2}=6$. Hence the result is
$$
\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to look at this. The sample space is:

$$S = \{RG,\ RB,\ RP,\ GR,\ GB,\ GP,\ BR,\ BG,\ BP,\ PR,\ PG,\ PB\}$$

Let $A$ be the event we choose a read pen
Let $B$ be the event we choose a green pen

Then counting the state space where we have $RG$ or $GR$, we get

$$P(A \cap B) = 4/12 = 1/3$$